# Facebook API Post Impressions Unique (reach)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm after the impression uniques for our posts and ideally we would like one server call and it would bring back the last 100 posts with the reach (post_impressions_unique).

To get reach, I can currently do this using:

https://graph.facebook.com/nmemagazine/posts?fields=name,message,full_picture,created_time,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true)&access_token=USER_TOKEN

and getting the post ID, then calling: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/POST_ID/insights/post_impressions_unique?access_token=USER_TOKEN

Is there a way where I can make one call to get all recent posts and their reach in one API call?

Comment: It doesn't look like this is possible since the post's contents and insights data can only be fetched from different API endpoints

Answer (score 2):

You could simply call

> https://graph.facebook.com/nmemagazine/posts?fields=name,message,full_picture,created_time,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true),insights&access_token=USER_TOKEN

NOTE: extra field "insights".

However, as far as I can tell you cannot limit the insights to just Post_impressions_Unique so it would bring back some data you do not necessarily want/need. I.e. I don't think you can perform a search/filter on a "second level"/child/nested type.

Answer (score 0):

To give an update on this:

In facebook Graph API 2.10, you can (and have to) specify the metrics you are interested in via insights.metric(...). Possible metrics are documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/insights#availmetrics

For your example:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/nmemagazine/posts?fields=name,message,full_picture,created_time,shares,likes.limit(1).summary(true),comments.limit(1).summary(true),insights.metric(post_impressions_unique)&access_token=USER_TOKEN"
```