# Facebook API: Get Post Impressions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i`d like to get the number of persons that where reached by my post.

I have tried `/{post_id}/insights/page_impressions` and anything else listed on the Facebook API-Documentation.

[Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/insights)

but i only get a emty data array and nothing else.

It seems like a lot of people don't get this number, is there any solution?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/34090275](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34090275)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions you've requested with the token and make sure that `read_insights` is included. Here's a screenshot from the API explorer:

[image: Ensure read_insights is selected on token permissions]

Comment: i have a working access token..is it possible to set this for an existing token? I only see that window when i request a new access token